# What Software was Bundled with My Old Mac?

Tags: mac, classic-mac-os

In the beginning of 1995, we bought a Macintosh Performa 5200. I remember that after registering the machine, we got a box with some bonus software on CDs. I certainly know that [The Daedalus Encounter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Daedalus_Encounter) came with it. This happened in Germany, if that matters.

What else came with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gosh, that's a blast from the past. I had to go digging (deep) in my office!

The Performa 5200 came with a software bundle that included:

- The Daedalus Encounter
- Grolier's Multimedia Encyclopedia
- Myst
- Mega Rock Rap 'n' Roll
- Making Music

I'm not sure if there was a difference with models sold in Germany (in fact I didn't think this particular model was ever sold in Germany).

However, other models in the Performa range of that era also came with the Apple Magic Collection. This included:

- A Lion King animated story book
- The Aladin Activity Center
- Toy Story demo CD

Comment: Yes, I also remember Myst. So, this sounds good! Thanks!

Comment: No worries. As an aside, I loved playing Myst. I still have the original box (CD and all). I might just have to start playing it again on one of my old Macs! :)

Comment: While I don't have any citable source, I'm pretty sure it was sold in Germany. It had 32+8 RAM configuration and a PAL TV receiver.

Comment: Feel free to add more appropriate tags to the question. I didn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

We had a Performa 6300 at that time. In addition to the software already mentioned, it also came with a Notation Software to write music with. I forgot the name though.